# attempt to re-open an already closed object: SQLiteQuery

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception, sqlite

I understand that this question has been asked several times but it seems to me that none of the other answers are applicable to my situation. I am trying to remove the 4 items in my database upon a button press, but I get an illegalstateexception when trying to do so. I have tried to delete my database in the following way, but it hasn't seemed to work:

```
getActivity().deleteDatabase("TABLE_CATTLE");
```

I have also tried using a loop to delete the entries one-by-one as such:

```
int cattle_i=0;
int numCattle = cattleDb.getCattleCount(); 
while(cattle_i<numCattle){
    Cattle cattle = cattleDb.getCattle(cattle_i);
    cattleDb.deleteCattle(cattle);
    cattle_i++;
}
```

Neither of these methods seem to be working for me. I only get the illegalstateexception when using the one-by-one approach. My code fails when calling the getCattleCount() method in my DatabaseHandler class, which I show below.

```
public int getCattleCount(){
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CATTLE;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

Here is the getCattle method:

```
Cattle getCattle(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CATTLE,  new String[] 
            {KEY_ID,  KEY_TAG_ID, KEY_ALIAS, KEY_TIME, KEY_DATA}, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] {String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor!=null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    Cattle cattle = new Cattle(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1),
            cursor.getString(2),
            cursor.getString(3),
            cursor.getString(4));
    cursor.close();
    db.close();//test
    return cattle;
}
```

deleteCattle method:

```
    //Deleting single cow
public void deleteCattle(Cattle cattle){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CATTLE, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] {String.valueOf(cattle.getID())});
    db.close();
}
```

Cattle Bean:

```
public class Cattle {

    // private variables
    int _id = 0;
    String _tag_id = null;
    String _alias = null;
    String _time_stamp = null;
    String _tag_data = null;
    String _user_email = null;

    // Empty Constructor
    public Cattle() {

    }

    // Constructor
    public Cattle(int id, String tag_id, String alias, String _time_stamp, String _tag_data) {
        this._id = id;
        this._tag_id = tag_id;
        this._alias = alias;
        this._time_stamp = _time_stamp;
        this._tag_data = _tag_data;
    }

    // Constructor
    public Cattle(String tag_id, String alias, String _time_stamp, String tag_data) {
        this._tag_id = tag_id;
        this._alias = alias;
        this._time_stamp = _time_stamp;
        this._tag_data = tag_data;
    }

    // getting ID
    public int getID() {
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting ID
    public void setID(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }

    // getting tagID
    public String getTagID() {
        return this._tag_id;
    }

    // setting tagID
    public void setTagID(String tag_id) {
        this._tag_id = tag_id;
    }

    // getting alias
    public String getAlias() {
        return this._alias;
    }

    // setting alias
    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this._alias = alias;
    }

    // getting time stamp
    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return this._time_stamp;
    }

    // setting time stamp
    public void setTimeStamp(String time_stamp) {
        this._time_stamp = time_stamp;
    }

    // getting tag data
    public String getTagData() {
        return this._tag_data;
    }

    // setting tag data
    public void setTagData(String tag_data) {
        this._tag_data = tag_data;
    }

}
```

edit: I used this tutorial to build my SQLiteDatabase
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You close the cursor in this line:

```
cursor.close();
```

And then try to use it in that one

```
return cursor.getCount();
```

This won't work as the cursor is already closed.

You can rewrite your method this way:

```
public int getCattleCount(){
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CATTLE;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return count;
}
```

Your `getCattle` should be:

```
Cattle getCattle(int id){
    Cattle cattle = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CATTLE,  new String[] 
            {KEY_ID,  KEY_TAG_ID, KEY_ALIAS, KEY_TIME, KEY_DATA}, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] {String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor!=null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cattle = new Cattle(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(3),
                cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    db.close();//test
    return cattle;
}
```

Comment: When I remove the cursor.close() line as you suggest, I still get an IllegalStateException, however this time it says 'cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed'.

Comment: The same line. It fails to return an integer when executing the line: return cursor.getCount();

Comment: Hmm.. now I get a cursor index out of bounds exception? It looks to me like it is ocurring on this line: Cattle cattle = cattleDb.getCattle(cattle_i);

Comment: I added my getCattle method to the question description.

Comment: I now get a null pointer exception in my deleteCattle method where I am calling a getID() method that is defined in my cattle bean class. I included both my java bean class as well as the deleteCattle method.

Comment: Aha! I had neglected the fact that the id indices start at 1 and not 0, hence when I tried to do cattleDb.getCattle(0), I would get a null pointer. Thank you so much Szymon! You deserve +rep, but I cannot give you any because I am a new user here :(

Comment: @Doug No worries. You can accept my answer if you think it deserves it. It will give you 2 rep so that you can start gaining it.